# Angular Authentification Guard Cookie Heroku

Tags: angular, authentication, heroku, cookies, guard

I use NodeJs 12 with Mongodb and Angular 8. I try to deploy on Heroku my application. In local, when I try to connect by login and password it works perfectly, I store JWT in Cookie and When I try to go in a protected route it's work because I catch my cookie jwt. But when I deploy this app on Heroku I can create a cookie with jwt, but I can't go in my protected route.

What is the problem?

app.js

```
app.get("/api/toto", checkAuth, (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({ message: "Le route toto" });
});
```

check-auth.js

```
 try {
    const token = req.cookies.auth || req.headers.authorization.split(".")[1];
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY);
    req.userData = { email: decoded.email, userId: decoded.userId };
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(401).json({ message: "Auth failed!" });
  }
```

auth-rotue.js

```
 const token = await jwt.sign(
    {
      id: findUser._id,
      prenom: findUser.prenom,
      roles: findUser.roles,
      email: findUser.email
    },
    process.env.SECRET_KEY,
    { expiresIn: 300000 }
  ); 
  res.cookie("auth", token, {
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + 300000),
    secure: true,
    httpOnly: true
  });
  return res.status(200).json({
    success: true,
    token: token,
    user: {
      name: findUser.name,
      email: findUser.email,
      age: findUser.age,
      roles: findUser.roles
    },
    expiresIn: 1200,
    message: "Authentication is succesfull !"
  });
```

token-interceptor.ts

```
 intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const token = this.tokenService.GetToken();
    const headersConfig = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    };
    if (token) {
      headersConfig['Auth'] = `${token}`;
    }
    const _req = req.clone({ setHeaders: headersConfig, withCredentials: true });
    return next.handle(_req);
  }
```

auth-service.ts

```
  private link = "yourlink";
  private urlPostLogin = this.link + "/api/auth/login";
  private protect = this.link + "/api/toto";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {}

  login(body): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(this.urlPostLogin, body);
  }

  toto() {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.protect);
  }
```

token-service.ts

```
  GetToken() {
    return this.cookieService.get("auth");
  }

  SetToken(token) {
    this.cookieService.set(
      "auth",
      token,
      new Date(Date.now() + 300000),
      "/",
      "/",
      true,
      "None"
    );
    // this.cookieService.set("auth", token, new Date(Date.now() + 300000));
  }

  DeleteToken() {
    this.cookieService.delete("auth");
  }

  GetPayload() {
    const token = this.GetToken();
    let payload;
    if (token) {
      console.log("jwt_decode(token): ", jwt_decode(token))
      payload = jwt_decode(token);
    }
    return payload;
  }
```

Comment: what is cookieService? Check if your cookie is in `document.cookie`

Comment: import { CookieService } from "ngx-cookie-service";

Answer (score 0):

I found, How can I go in protected route, in node I change this:

```
{  
   secure: false,
   httpOnly: false 
}
```

But, I don't understand why it's not works When I use

```
{  
   secure: true,
   httpOnly: true 
}
```